# Converting year weeks to continuous without gaps in Power BI graph

Tags: scroll, powerbi

I have weekly sales data from 201601-201835 and i have to create a graph to see the trend. Since the data is categorical, a scroll bar is appearing on the graph. I want to view the complete graph at once.
I tried converting the data to continuous, but there is a gap in the graph as there is no data from 201653 to 201699 and hence the graph is wrong. 
Is there a way of viewing the complete data without a scroll bar?

Comment: Use a date column. If you don't have one, generate it.

Answer (score 0):

I would add summary fields to the Axis above the Week, e.g. Year, Month, Quarter.  You will probably need a reference table for your weeks or some fancy calculations.

With those fields in place, you can expand or drill into the levels before getting down to the Week level.  As the higher levels are Categorical and have fewer categories, you are less likely to see scroll bars.

A side benefit is the user has more control e.g. they can drill down on just a section of the weeks, e.g. for one year.